# How come the view won’t update after user finish registration?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I would like to ask everyone here that how come the view won’t update after user finish registration ?

Im using firebase addsnapshotlistener to fetch data base on the place where the user is.
For example. A user finish registration with information that : userName: Peter
City: New York, Area: Queen, then addsnapshotlistener should auto fetch the data info from

```
whereField(“city”, isEqualTo:: “user.user.city”), whereField(“area”, isEqualTo:: “user.user.area”)
```

But the view just will not. I have to kill app, reopen it to show data in view.
I have no any idea how to fix that.

So please any one knows what’s wrong with my code?
I’m so new with programing, I’m just self-learning Swiftui for about half year, it is also my first language.

Its pretty long, but really hope that can fix it.
I will appreciate so much if someone could give me any idea how to fix it.

Here’s my code.

Class fetch Data and struct:

```
struct RecruitInfo: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var userId: String
    var commodityName: String
    var describe: String
    var recruitNumber: Int
    var place: String
    var date: String
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var area: String
    var systemDate: Date
    var isHide: Bool
    var isFull: Bool
    var joiningPeople: [String]
    var beReported: [String]
}

class Recruit: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var recruits = [RecruitInfo]()  
    @Published var manageRecruits = [ManageRecruitInfo]() 
    @Published var message = [Message]()
    @Published var lastMessageId = ""
    @Published var chatRoomId = ""
   
    let now: Date = Date.now
    
    @ObservedObject var user = User()
    @ObservedObject var messagemanager = MessageManager()
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

func getRecruitData() {
        
        db.collection("Recruit")*.whereField("city", isEqualTo: user.user.city).whereField("area", isEqualTo: user.user.area)*.whereField("isFull", isEqualTo: false).whereField("isHide", isEqualTo: false).whereField("systemDate", isLessThanOrEqualTo: now).order(by: "systemDate", descending: true).limit(to: 150).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            guard let recruits = snapshot?.documents else {
                print("error fetch documents: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            
            
                self.recruits = recruits.compactMap({ document -> RecruitInfo? in
                    
                        do {
                            return try document.data(as: RecruitInfo.self)

                        } catch {
                            print("error decoding : \(error)")
                            return nil
                        }
                    
                })
          
                self.recruits.sort { $0.systemDate > $1.systemDate}
            
                
                self.recruits = self.recruits.filter({ RecruitInfo in
                    return RecruitInfo.beReported.doesNotContain(self.user.user.id)
                })
        }
    }


    init() {
         getRecruitData()
         getManageRecruitData()
    }
```

user info class and struct

```
struct UserInfo: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var area: String
}

class User: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    
    @Published var user = UserInfo(id: UUID().uuidString, name: "", city: "", area: "")
    
    func NewUserSignUp(name: String, city: String, area: String) {
        let newUserId = user.id
        let newUserName = name
        let newUserCity = city
        let newUserArea = area
        
        let newUser = UserInfo(id: newUserId, name: newUserName, city: newUserCity, area: newUserArea)
        
        
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newUser) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "userInfo")
        }
        
        user = newUser
        
        db.collection("Users").document(newUserId).setData(["area" : area,
                                                     "id" : newUserId,
                                                     "name" : name,
                                                     "city" : city,
                                                     "signupDate" : Date.now], merge: true) { error in
            
            if error == nil {
                print("Register Succeed")
                
            } else {
                // handle the error
                print("Register Failed")
            }
            
        }
  
    }
    
    func OldUserDefaults(city: String, area: String) {
        let oldUser = UserInfo(id: user.id, name: user.name, city: city, area: area)
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(oldUser) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "userInfo")
        }
        
        user = oldUser
    }
    
    
    init() {
        if let savedUser = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "userInfo") {
            if let decodedUser = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserInfo.self, from: savedUser) {
                user = decodedUser
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

user regitration page

```
struct RegisterView: View {
    @ObservedObject var recruit = Recruit()
        
    @State private var showRulesView = false
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @StateObject var user = User()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LogoPage()

            
            Text("Data match will your regitraion info")
                .padding(.top, 1)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
            
            if user.user.name == "" {
                
                NewUserRegisterView()
                    .environmentObject(user)
                
            } else {
                
                OldUserRegisterView()
            }
 
            Divider()
            
            HStack {
                Text("Agree")
                Button("Rules") {
                    showRulesView = true
                }
                
            }
            
            Button("Close") {
                dismiss()
            }
            .padding(.top, 150)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showRulesView) {
            RulesView()
        }
    }
}
```

new user regitration view

```
struct NewUserRegisterView: View {
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var city: String = ""
    @State private var area: String = ""
    @State private var showEmptyAlert = false
    @State private var showSueeccededAlert = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    @ObservedObject var recruit = Recruit()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section {
                
                TextField("User Name", text: $name)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(5)
                    .shadow(radius: 1)
                    
                TextField("City", text: $city)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(5)
                    .shadow(radius: 1)
                
                TextField("Area", text: $area)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(5)
                    .shadow(radius: 1)
            }
            Spacer()
                
            Button() {
                
                if name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty || city.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty || area.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty {
                    showEmptyAlert = true
                    } else {
                        showSueeccededAlert = true
                        
                        user.NewUserSignUp(name: name, city: city, area: area)
                                     
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text("Register")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight:30)
                    .background(Color("titlerowbuttoncolor"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding(5)
            }
            
            .alert("", isPresented: $showEmptyAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) {}
            } message: {
                Text("can not be empty")
            }
            
            
            .alert("", isPresented: $showSueeccededAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) {
                    
                    dismiss()
                }
            } message: {
                Text("Succeed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the view should be updated

```
struct ShowRecruitView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var user = User()
    @State private var RegisterViewShowSheet = false
    @State private var RecruitViewShowSheet = false
    @ObservedObject var recruit = Recruit()
    let lastOne: Int = 1
    
    @State private var showYouAreIn: Bool = false
    @State private var showReportAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var showReportSelfAlert: Bool = false
    //@State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
              MainPageTitleRowView()

                  ScrollView {
                          LazyVStack {
                              ForEach(recruit.recruits, id: \.id) { recruitInfo in
                                      HStack {
                                          Button(){
                                              if recruitInfo.joiningPeople.contains(user.user.id) {
                                                  showYouAreIn = true
                                                  
                                              } else {
                                                  
                                                  if recruitInfo.recruitNumber - recruitInfo.joiningPeople.count > lastOne {
                                                      
                                                          recruit.updateRecruitJoiningPeopleData(updateRecruit: recruitInfo, updateJoiningPeople: user.user.id)
                          
                                                  } else if recruitInfo.recruitNumber - recruitInfo.joiningPeople.count == lastOne {
                                                      
                                                          recruit.updateRecruitJoiningPeopleData(updateRecruit: recruitInfo, updateJoiningPeople: user.user.id)
                                                          
                                                          recruit.UpdateisFullValue(recruit: recruitInfo)

                                                  }
                                              }
                        
                                          } label: {
                                              Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                                  .padding(1)
                                                  //.padding(.top, 10)
                                                  //.padding(.bottom, 10)
                                                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                  .font(.title3)
                                                  .cornerRadius(5, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
                                                  .frame(maxWidth: 30)
                                          }
                                          
                                          RecruitInfoView(recruitInfo: recruitInfo, isShowReportAlert: $showReportAlert, isShowReportSelfAlert: $showReportSelfAlert)
                                              
                                          
                                      }
                                      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 300)
                                      .background(Color.blue)
                                      .cornerRadius(5)
                                      .padding(2)

                                  
                              }
                          }
                      
                      
                      
                  }
              
                  .alert("", isPresented: $showYouAreIn) {
                      Button("OK", role: .cancel) {}
                  } message: {
                      Text("This is your recruit")
                  }
              
                  .alert("", isPresented: $showReportAlert) {
                      Button("OK", role: .cancel) {}
                  } message: {
                      Text("Already reported this recruit")
                  }
              
                  .alert("", isPresented: $showReportSelfAlert) {
                      Button("OK", role: .cancel) {}
                  } message: {
                      Text("Can not report your own recruit")
                  }
                  
                
            }

     
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Two much code but less information here; need MRE.  You need to be more specific on which lines of codes and when did your code start to fail. Right now, what I'm seeing is your `ShowRecruitView` view uses `Recruit()` class, but `NewUserRegisterView` view uses `User()` class. Are you sure in your `Recruit()` class, you use the correct api link for the snapshot listener?

Comment: What I expect is 
>New user finished registration then update **User()** Class <before registration, no data from Userdefaults, so default the user info is UserInfo(id: UUID().uuidString, name: "", city: "", area: "")>

> **Recruit()** Class using updated user info to fetch data from firebase.    < I guess now situation is **Recruit()** class still using the default user info(which is city: "", area: "") to listen the data from firebase > 

>lastly **ShowRecruitView** show the data.
But actually I am not really sure which part is going wrong exactly…
thank you for your reply anyway!